# Even number of heads

Tags: probability

Let there be an even number of tosses of the same unbiased coin. Show that
the probability of an even number of heads turning up can be expressed as a power of $\frac{1}{2}$.

I know this has being asked previously and the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ but the last part is throwing me, is it sufficient to just write $\frac{1}{2}$ or should it be $\frac{1}{2^n}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ to another power?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the final toss and its impact on the parity

Answer (score 2):

After all-but-one of the tosses, you have an even or odd number of heads so far.  Now consider the final toss:

- If the number of heads so far is even, the probability it stays even is $\frac12$ as you have an unbiased coin with probability $\frac12$ of being tails on the final toss
- If the number of heads so far is odd, the probability it becomes even is $\frac12$ as you have an unbiased coin  with probability $\frac12$ of being heads on the final toss

So the probability the final number of heads is even must be $\frac12$.
(This argument works for odd numbers of tosses too.)

Comment: i know the answer is 1/2 but my confusion was since it said it can be expressed as a power of 1/2. It sounds stupid but should i write it as 1/2^1 or is just 1/2 correct?

Comment: @MikeHunt $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1=\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$ are all equivalent answers and are all correct.  If you want to heavily emphasize the "*power of*" aspect of it, then go ahead and use the first... but it is strange to write anything as a first power since it simplifies immediately to as though the exponent weren't written at all.

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thanks was just confirming this

Comment: I suspect the real question may be to show the numerator is $1$ as the probability of any event based on a finite even number of tosses of an unbiased coin can be written with a denominator of $2^{2n}$, but may not be a power of $\frac12$, for example the probability the numbers of heads and tails are equal is not a power of $\frac12$ when $2n>2$